# Only update specific column using Z.EntityFramework.Plus' SingleUpdate method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

In my project, I want to update a specifiy data set's column using Z.EntityFramework.Plus. I'm using the following code:

```cs
await db.Features.SingleUpdateAsync(new Feature()
{
    ID = featureInfo.ID,
    Unit = unit,
});
```

The `Feature` class consists of multiple columns. I only want to update the `Unit` column for a given `ID`. However, this statement always tries to reset all the other columns to `null`. So I think that I've misunderstood how this method works in general.

How can I update only the given unit value without modifying (or having to load) all the other values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by using the `Where` and [UpdateFromQuery](https://entityframework-extensions.net/update-from-query):

```
await db.Features.Where(x => x.ID == featureInfo.ID).UpdateFromQuery(x => new Feature()
{
    Unit = unit
});
```

For multiple IDs, if the unit is a constant:

```
await db.Features.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ID)).UpdateFromQuery(x => new Feature()
{
    Unit = unit
});
```

If you have thousand/million IDs, is also possible to use the [WhereBulkContains](https://entityframework-extensions.net/where-bulk-contains) method (this one is not free):

```
await db.Features.WhereBulkContains(ids).UpdateFromQuery(x => new Feature()
{
    Unit = unit
});
```

**EDIT: Answer Comment**

> Is there any documentation for the SingleUpdateAsync method I was using

There is no documentation. It works exactly like `BulkUpdate` but allows you to pass a single entity instead of a list (this is the only difference).

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution. Is there any documentation for the `SingleUpdateAsync` method I was using? Or is it for internal use only?